# Add HTML attribute for field in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2, onepage-checkout, field

it's possible add custom attribute in div (or input) that contain field of checkout in $jsLayout array?

In my case i want add tabindex attribute

[image: In this screenshot add additionalClass (checkout-field__telephone)]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can override input field using $jsLayout array in you custom module.
Hope you know how to create Layoutprocessor plugin.

In you Layoutprocessor override text field file 'elementTmpl' to your custom file from custom module like below code

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['telephone']['config']['elementTmpl'] = 'Vendor_Module/form/element/telephone';
```

And in you html file you can add your attribute like below `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/form/element/telephone.html`

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<input class="input-text" type="tel" tabindex="3" data-bind="
    value: value,
    valueUpdate: 'keyup',
    hasFocus: focused,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        'aria-describedby': getDescriptionId(),
        'aria-required': required,
        'aria-invalid': error() ? true : 'false',
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled
    }" />
```

Comment: Hi Ranganathan, i know the possibility to override html but it is possible not to override the file but simply add an attribute to the parent div (because otherwise I would have to override every type of field)? Otherwise I would have to add many html files just to change an attribute (tabindex in my case)

Answer (score 0):

You could copy this file

`vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/templates/form/element/input.html:7`

to your app/design/ folder and add tabindex to the attr like this

```
<input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="
    value: value,
    valueUpdate: 'keyup',
    hasFocus: focused,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        'aria-describedby': getDescriptionId(),
        'aria-required': required,
        'aria-invalid': error() ? true : 'false',
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled,
        'tabindex': tabindex()
    }" />
```

and then create a js file which extends the abstract and add your function to it

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract'
], function (Abstract) {
    'use strict';

    return Abstract.extend({
        tabindex: function() {
           return 'what you need to return';
        }
    })
})
```

then you should have an attribute like I have test="HELLO" here: